# Displaying XML data with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to display some XML data in a jsp file.

I'm using EL to get the data below:

```
<xml id="xmlData">
    <c:out value="${xmlform.myXmlData}" escapeXml="false"/>
</xml>
```

How can I get reference to this xml document using javascript?

```
var xmlDoc  = document.getElementById("xmlData"); //reference to the xml element 
var xmlData = xmlDoc.[how to reference xmlDoc to get data?]
var fields  = xmlData.documentElement.selectNodes("field");
for (var i=-; i<fields.length;etc...
```

Comment: Where does this xml appear?  In the HTML of a web page?  As a result from an ajax request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the JSP-Server write the XML-tree directly in the HTML-code. I hope this could be helpful for you.

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(document.getElementById("xmlData").innerHTML ,"text/xml");
var fields = xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("field");
for(var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++)
{
    console.log(fields[i].firstChild.data); // fields[i].attributes, fields[i]childNodes, ...
}
```

or shorter:

```
var xmlData = document.getElementById("xmlData");
var fields = xmlData.getElementsByTagName("field");
for(var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++)
{
    console.log(fields[i].firstChild.data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to load your xml file in and then find and manipulate the Nodes as needed.

```
function loadXMLDoc(filename)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else // code for IE5 and IE6
  {
  xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xhttp.open("GET",filename,false);
xhttp.send();
return xhttp.responseXML;
}
```

All modern browsers have a built-in XML parser.

An XML parser converts an XML document into an XML DOM object - which can then be manipulated with JavaScript.

[W3Schools example](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_parser.asp)

Comment: Thanks for the tip user, will look into this

Comment: Please don't use W3Schools. Use [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org) instead. Examples can be hosted on http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can parse XML in javascript.

```
var xmlDoc;

function parsexml(txt)
{
    if (window.DOMParser)
      {
      parser=new DOMParser();
      xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(txt,"text/xml");  //txt is your xml data
      }
    else // Internet Explorer
      {
      xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
      xmlDoc.async=false;
      xmlDoc.loadXML(txt); 
      }
}
function getElementFromXML(tagname)
{
return xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName(tagname)[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}
```